# Getting Cumulative Sum Over Time

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data with goals scored for each player each season:

```r
playerID <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)
year <- c(2002,2000,2000,2003,2001,2001,2000,2002,2002,2001,2003,2003)
goals <- c(25,21,27,31,39,34,42,44,46,59,55,53)
my_data <- data.frame(playerID, year, goals)
```

I would like to plot each player's **cumulative** number of goals over time:

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=year, y=cumsum_goals, group=playerID)) + geom_line()
```

I have tried using `summarize` from `dplyr`, but this only works if the data is already sorted by `year` (see player 1):

```
new_data <- my_data %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_goals=cumsum(goals))
```

Is there a way to make this code robust to data where years are not in chronological order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `arrange` by `playerID` and `year`, take `cumsum` and then plot

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

my_data %>%
  arrange(playerID, year) %>%
  group_by(playerID) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_goals=cumsum(goals)) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=year, y= cumsum_goals, color = factor(playerID)) + geom_line()
```

[image]